# Anyone got any examples of, or experience with the use of Imagick::setImageClipMask?

Tags: imagick

I'm struggling to get it to work.
$text_layer->setImageClipMask($mask_layer);
I'm expecting all the black areas of $mask_layer to erase the matching areas of $text_layer.
It doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The [`compositeImage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) method can achieve the effect you're seeking. In PHP, you could do something like this:

```php
<?php

// Open image
$image = new \Imagick('image.png');

// Create, draw mask
$mask = new \Imagick();
$mask->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), 'transparent', 'png');

$mask_shape = new \ImagickDraw();
$mask_shape->setStrokeAntialias(true);

$mask_shape->setFillColor('white');
$mask_shape->setStrokeColor('white');
$mask_shape->circle($image_width/2, $image_height/2, 0, $image_height/2);

$mask->drawImage($mask_shape);

// Apply mask to image
$image->compositeImage($mask, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);

// Save newly-"masked" image
$image->writeImage('image.png');
```

A before and after:

[image]

Preferably, you would create a mask in Photoshop and store it with your project. You can open your mask like so `$mask = new \Imagick('mask.png');` and apply it directly without dynamically generating a mask like I did above.

Comment: For whatever reason, when dumping the image out as a result like this it appeared that nothing happened.  I have to composite it onto a blank image before I got the mask to "apply": ```$copy = new Imagick();
   $copy->newImage($width, $height, 'transparent', 'png');
   $copy->compositeImage($im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

   $im->destroy();
   $im = $copy;```